# flush bottom an environment

Tags: vertical-alignment, environments

Suppose, I have defined an environment called `myenvironment` which typesets multiple lines of text using various formats. So, the height of the environment depends on the text that it has which is different each time. 
What I need it to place the text at the bottom of the page. If in the definition of this environment I use `\vspace*{\fill}`, it does not work. Any solution for this?

MWE:

```
\newenvironment{myenvironment}{\vspace*{\fill}
  \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
    \begin{center}
    OUTLINE OF THIS CHAPTER
    \end{center}
    \vspace*{-6pt}\sffamily\fontsize{12}{14}%
    \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}%
    \hrule height 0.5pt width \textwidth \vspace*{10pt}%
    }%End of the begining commands
  {\vspace*{10pt}%
  \hrule height 0.5pt width \textwidth
  \end{minipage}}
```

Comment: A [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) is necessary.

Comment: Note that the following works (i.e., produces flushbottom text) for me: `\documentclass{article}\newenvironment{myenv}{\vspace*{\fill}}{}\usepackage{lipsum}\begin{document}\lipsum[1]\begin{myenv}\lipsum[1]\end{myenv}\end{document}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to break the page immediately after the environment, otherwise `\vspace*{\fill}` won't do what you're expecting.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newenvironment{myenvironment}
 {\par\vspace*{\fill} % better ensuring we are between paragraphs
  \noindent\begin{minipage}{\textwidth} % \noindent
  \begin{center}
  OUTLINE OF THIS CHAPTER
  \end{center}
  \vspace*{-6pt}\large\sffamily % better using a high level command
  \hrule height 0.5pt width \textwidth \vspace*{10pt}%
 }%End of the begining commands
 {\vspace*{10pt}%
  \hrule height 0.5pt width \textwidth
  \end{minipage}\newpage % end this page
 }

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{myenvironment}
\lipsum*[2]
\end{myenvironment}

\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

Note that setting `\parindent` to zero in a `minipage` is redundant, because LaTeX does it automatically.

Comment: **You have to break immediately**. How should I know this?

Comment: @rowman TeX always tries to put in a page as much material as it can; the `\vspace*{\fill}` instruction tells to fill with white space *after* the best page break has been found. With `\newpage` you're telling TeX that no more material is accepted in the page.

Comment: Informative explanation of `\vspace*{\fill}` ! Thanks!